# Use for loop with if else statement in R

Tags: r, mechanicalturk

I am trying to create a for loop with an if else statement. My code looks the following:

```
for(i in 1:length(assignmentlist[,1]))
{if assignmentlist$Approve[i]=="1"
      {ApproveAssignment(assignments=assignmentlist$AssignmentId[i],sandbox=T)}
  else {RejectAssignment(assignments=assignmentlist$AssignmentId[i],sandbox=T)}}
```

whereas the "assignmentlist" looks like the following

```
> assignmentlist
   AssignmentId    Approve                   
1          5135          1 
2          8963          0
3          6823          0
4          3287          1
```

Basically I would like to execute the "ApproveAssignment" function for all the entries that have a "1" in the "Approve" collumn. The problem is, that I would like to use the same index (the same i) **inside** the ApproveAssignment function. Unfortunately, this does not seem to work. Does anyone has a gentle way to avoid this problem?

Edit: The Approve Assignment function is a function that approves a certain assignment of Mechanical Turk over an API and is part of the MTurkR package

Any help yould be appreciated very much!

Comment: What does the ApproveAssignment function roughly do? There is a function called ifelse that works on vectors or you could use the apply function. What kind of output do you kind of want?

Comment: The ApproveAssignment function approves an assignment of Mechanical Turk (a Crowdsourcing platform) over an API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't get the point because the "i" of youy loop can be directly used in your function:

```
ApproveAssignment <- function(assignments=NULL, sandbox=NULL) cat(i, "was approved\n")
RejectAssignment <- function(assignments=NULL, sandbox=NULL) cat(i, "was rejected\n")

for(i in 1:length(assignmentlist[,1])){
  if (assignmentlist$Approve[i]=="1")
    ApproveAssignment(assignments=assignmentlist$AssignmentId[i],sandbox=T)
  else
    RejectAssignment(assignments=assignmentlist$AssignmentId[i],sandbox=T)
    }
```

Comment: Oh, I am so sorry, it was only the brackets I forgot around the first if statement, that were the error. Everything else works fine! I searched the error in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

If, which I assume given I you want to use it inside it, you are the author of `ApproveAssignment`, you should hand the index over to the function as an additional argument.

```
ApproveAssignment <- function(assignments, sandbox, index) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ApproveAssignment` and `RejectAssignment` internally loop through a vector of AssignmentIds to make an assignment-specific call to the API, so all you have to do is feed it a vector of AssignmentIds, no need for the loop or any of the conditionals.

```
ApproveAssignment(assignments=assignmentlist$AssignmentId[assignmentlist$Approve==1],sandbox=T)
RejectAssignment(assignments=assignmentlist$AssignmentId[!assignmentlist$Approve==1],sandbox=T)
```